# ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' returned status code 143

Tags: git, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins ver. 2.32.1 installed on my iMac and I have set up the git repository for my project and provided my credentials as well.
Note: Repository is private. When the repository is cloned from Windows it works fine but when same repository is cloned from iMac it is giving below log and it is returning status code `143`.

```
Started by user XYZ
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Project1
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Organization/Repository # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Organization/Repository
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
> git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/Organization/Repository +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/Organization/Repository
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:803)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1063)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/Organization/Repository +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1772)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1516)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:67)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:318)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:801)
... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have installed the Git plugin, but I am not able to understand why it is not able to get the code from GitHub. Can anyone help me by seeing the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, issue was that my jenkins was not having complete access of my user though it was installed completely in another user & was showing jenkins path. When I reinstalled Jenkins in my user & provided it complete access it worked.

Comment: Hi iYoung, I'm a newbie to Jenkins and I saw the same error as you. Could you please tell me how to "reinstalled Jenkins in my user & provided it complete access"? I just do (1) Download Jenkins.
(2) Open up a terminal in the download directory and run java -jar jenkins.war (3) Browse to http://localhost:8080 and follow the instructions to complete the installation.        Is it enough? Sorry I'm pretty new to terminal, if you can add some details, that will be great. thanks a looooot.

Answer (score 3):

How did you installed Jenkins **Command line** or the **Java pkg**?

The above seems to be the issue of User access. The User by which you installed Jenkins and the user by which u logged in your mac and accessing Jenkins might be different.

Try installing Jenkins from command line. This link may help [Install Jenkins](http://www.zymr.com/jenkins-integration-with-ios-part-2-of-3/)

Answer (score 2):

I installed Jenkins on Mac OS Sierra(10.12.4 (16E195)) by using the pkg file, encountered same issue. Because I am just using it for experimental purpose, thus I removed all the installation following [official guide](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+OSX+Installer). And download the war package option, and run using

> java -jar jenkins.war

Then the issue is gone.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I restarted the Mac that was running Jenkins, it started working.

Restarting from command line:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 0):

This is either due to incorrect user credentials or the time taken to checkout is taken more than 10 min, so it timed out Make sure your credential is correct, if so try after sometime.

Note : i cannot comment on the question , so replying as answer.

Comment: Credentials is definitely not an issue here. I tried setting timeout for 20 minutes but it is picking default time of 10 minutes. Can you help me how can I increase timeout time?

Comment: this doc may help you , i never tried it though . https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-ssh-push-timeout-on-large-changes-779171775.html   .

Comment: plugin.bitbucket-git.backend.timeout.idle=1800 Defines the idle timeout for push/pull processes, applying a limit to how long the operation is allowed to execute without either producing output or consuming input. The default value is 30 minutes. 
This value is in SECONDS.

Comment: plugin.bitbucket-git.backend.timeout.execution=86400 Defines the execution timeout for push/pull processes, applying a hard limit to how long the operation is allowed to run even if it is producing output or reading input. The default value is 1 day. 
This value is in SECONDS.

Comment: I am not using bit bucket, i am using git

Answer (score 0):

Update this post:
I'm using Mac and seeing the same issue. **I have a workaround.**

If you install Jenkins by using the pkg file, it will be in `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/workspace`, you will have this trouble.

If you install Jenkins by using the war file, it will be in `/Users/[your_computer_name]/.jenkins/jobs/workspace`, you are good.

I don't what is the root cause since I'm very junior, but I hope this will unblock you.

> If you know the root cause, please comment here and help more people.

thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.I resolved it by using ssh instead of https in the git url in the job configuration page.

The repository url needed to be changed from
https://${giturl}/repo.git to git@${giturl}/repo.git